# Get multiply key'value in object that have the same key

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, object

JSON data:

```
[{"name":"David","text":"Hi"},{"name":"Test_user","text":"test"},{"name":"David","text":"another text"}]
```

I want loop that search for e.g. David's texts and show it in HTML:

```
<h1>Hi</h1>
<h1>another text</h1>
```

I'm sorry for the bad expression but I don't know how to explain this.

Comment: you can group by 'name' then get the values of the object

Comment: Iterate and accumulate. Show your attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### HTML Content

```html
<div class="wrapper">

</div>
```

#### JS Content

```js
const list = [
    {"name": "David", "text": "Hi"},
    {"name": "Test_user", "text": "test"},
    {"name": "David","text": "another text"}
];

const searchKey = 'David';

// filter the objects with name "David" or "david"
const searchResult = list.filter(({ name }) => name.toLowerCase() === searchKey.toLowerCase());

// render the filtered array on HTML
const parentWrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
searchResult.forEach((el) => {
    const child = document.createElement('h1');
    child.textContent = el.text;
    parentWrapper.appendChild(child);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

here is a tested quick code to help me get the duplicates, I'm printing them, but you can store it or return it..

```
arr = [
  { name: "David", text: "Hi" },
  { name: "Test_user", text: "test" },
  { name: "David", text: "another text" },
];

const groupBy = (arrayInput, key) => {
  return arrayInput.reduce(
    (r, v, i, a, k = v[key]) => ((r[k] || (r[k] = [])).push(v), r),
    {}
  );
};

groupedByName = groupBy(arr, "name");

ans = Object.entries(groupedByName).map(([key, value]) => {
  if (value.length > 1) {
    // here is the list of duplicate for name: key
    const duplicates = value.map((item) => item.text);
    console.log(`name ${key} has duplicates: `, duplicates);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that what you want is something like this:

```
const myArray = [{"name":"David","text":"Hi"},{"name":"Test_user","text":"test"},{"name":"David","text":"another text"}]

const davidData = myArray.find(i => i.name === "David") // = {"name":"David","text":"Hi"}
```